# Regarding PLPYTHONU and requests module in AWS EC2 install

Tags: postgresql

I've hit a wall in trying to upgrade requests from 1.2.3 to something newer so I can call it inside of a plpythonu function.

No matter where I point it, it always comes back with version 1.2.3, for example, I have a 2.22.0 install located in /var/lib/pgsql95/data/requests, using this code, I always get 1.2.3 back - what am I missing?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testimport()
RETURNS text
AS $$
        try:
            import sys
            sys.path.append( '/var/lib/pgsql95/data/requests' )
            import requests 
            return requests.__version__
        except ImportError, e:
            return 'FAILURE'
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

SELECT * FROM testimport();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible explanations:

- when you update to "requests 2.22.0", for some reason, a .pyc file of the version 1.2.3 is not updated (for instance the date of the request.py 2.22.0 is older than the .pyc of the version 1.2.3).
- or when you update to "requests 2.22.0", the plpythonu function that is already loaded does not reload the new version on the instruction `import requests` (that is the standard python behaviour).